# How to solve `Error creating config for VM: Invalid JSON` in minishift?

Tags: openshift, minishift

```
minishift start
```

was issued and openshift started:

```
Login to server ...
Creating initial project "myproject" ...
Server Information ...
OpenShift server started.

The server is accessible via web console at:
    https://192.168.42.37:8443/console

You are logged in as:
    User:     developer
    Password: <any value>

To login as administrator:
    oc login -u system:admin


-- Exporting of OpenShift images is occuring in background process with pid 32067.
```

At a certain moment, the laptop ran out of free disk space. Once this issue was solved, an attempt was done to restart the minishift, but all commands return:

```
Error creating config for VM: Invalid JSON
```

**Attempts to solve the issue**

1. It turned out that a minishift process was still running. Killing this process and subsequently run `minishift status` returned the same issue.
2. `sudo systemctl restart libvirtd` did not solve the issue
3. [@tm1701](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025920/2777965) suggested `minishift delete --clear-cache`, but that does not solve the issue either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to solve this issue is a suggestion as provided by [@AndreasGajdosik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889996/2777965), i.e. deleting the `.minishift` directory.

Once `rm -rf ~/.minishift` was issued and `minishift status` was run, the issue has been solved:

```
user@host$ minishift status
Does Not Exist
```